# Create App Subfolder in Android

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm working in a Xamarin project and I need to know how to create a folder inside the app folder programmatically. The function we use to write logs uses relative paths based on the .exe location in Windows, so what I need to know is the app path to create a subfolder which will contain all generated logs.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `System`'s namespace provided class `Environment`. Like this:

```
var appPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
```

Remember that this `Personal` folder is created automatically to your app when it's installed and it's not accessible by other apps. If you want to share your logs, you can use another options like:

```
var androidDownloadsPath = Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDownloads;
```

Or even:

```
var rootPath = Android.OS.Environment.RootDirectory;
var dataPath = Android.OS.Environment.DataDirectory;
```

Having the Read/Write permissions you can create your subfolders there.

Comment: Ye thank you so much, that's what I was trying but since i couldn't see the folder I was creating I thought I was doing something wrong. 
I've created the folder and log files inside successfully, but is there any way to make these files visible?

Comment: Forgot to mention that I have enabled the show hidden files option, so it's about how to create accesible files inside the app folder. Thanks

Comment: There's no way to make your personal forder visible. Instead, you can create a directory at the root or at the data folder with your app's name and put the logs there. Didn't it fits?